# How to make a description list aligned by pairs with Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am new to flexbox and I have been trying to make a description list aligned in pairs stacked on top of each other like in a table.

I have tried some flexbox techniques but nothing is working

This is the markup

```
<div class="ad-overview">
                    <h3>Overview</h3>
                    <dl>
                        <dt>Mileage(KM)</dt>
                        <dd>4300</dd>

                        <dt>Condition</dt>
                        <dd>Locally used</dd>

                        <dt>Body Type</dt>
                        <dd>4 wheel drives & Suvs</dd>

                        <dt>Colour</dt>
                        <dd>Black</dd>

                        <dt>Fuel</dt>
                        <dd>Diesel</dd>

                        <dt>Transmission</dt>
                        <dd>Automatic</dd>

                        <dt>Duty Type</dt>
                        <dd>Paid</dd>

                        <dt>Interior</dt>
                        <dd>Leather</dd>

                        <dt>Engine size</dt>
                        <dd>2993</dd>

                        <dt>Year</dt>
                        <dd>2012</dd>

                    </dl>
                </div>
```

This is my css

```
.ad-overview,
dl {
    display: flex;
}

dl {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

dt {
    font-weight: bold;
}

dt+dd {
    display: flex;
}
```

This is the layout style I am trying to achieve. Some help would be appreciated
[image: overview]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's many solutions to your problem, the simpliest one is by putting each pair of td and dd inside a block, and set that block as a flexbox with a `flex-direction:column`, and you will also have to add a wrap to make it look stacked, this is the main idea, then you will have to make some modifications on the code for the margin for example, the width of your blocks and so on, these are up to you, the following code will show you the solution:

```css
.ad-overview,
dl {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.col{
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
text-align:left;
width: 30%;
margin-bottom: 3%;
}

dt {
    font-weight: bold;
}
dd{
margin-left:0px;
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="ad-overview">
                    <h3>Overview</h3>
                    <dl>
                        <div class="col">
                          <dt>Mileage(KM)</dt>
                          <dd>4300</dd>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                          <dt>Condition</dt>
                          <dd>Locally used</dd>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                          <dt>Body Type</dt>
                          <dd>4 wheel drives & Suvs</dd>
                         </div>
                         <div class="col">
                          <dt>Colour</dt>
                          <dd>Black</dd>
                          </div>
                          
                       <div class="col">
                          <dt>Fuel</dt>
                          <dd>Diesel</dd>
                          </div>
                          
                       <div class="col">
                          <dt>Transmission</dt>
                          <dd>Automatic</dd>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col">
                          <dt>Duty Type</dt>
                          <dd>Paid</dd>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col">
                          <dt>Interior</dt>
                          <dd>Leather</dd>
                       </div>
                          
                       <div class="col">
                          <dt>Engine size</dt>
                          <dd>2993</dd>
                       </div>
                          
                       <div class="col">
                          <dt>Year</dt>
                          <dd>2012</dd>
                       </div>

                    </dl>
                </div>
```

Comment: You might want to test this thoroughly because only recently was adding `<div>`s as direct children of a `<dl>` considered valid. I also recommend putting any rule that uses `flex-wrap` within an `@supports` block.